# The set of irrationals numbers is countable?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, infinity

I tried to prove this using statement using the difference of sets
$\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

In general, is it possible to say that "Let $A$, $B$ and $C$  be sets such that $B$ is not countable and $C$ is countable. If $A=B-C$, then A is countable." ?

Comment: An uncountable set missing a countable subset is still uncountable. So no, $A$ is not enumerable.

Comment: I think you may have an issue with language and negatives - what you have written does not make much sense, but you seem to have a better idea of the concepts than you have expressed in your question (assuming English is not your natural language).

Comment: There are even subsets of the irrational numbers that are still uncountable, including every interval with a positive length , the transcendental numbers and the uncomputable numbers (being a subset of the transcendental numbers)

Answer (score 1):

The set of irrational numbers is no enumarable. If  $\mathbb{R}$ - $\mathbb{Q}$ was enumarable, $\mathbb{R}$ would be union two countable sets which is countable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).